# Trying to save a model to a pb file and I don't have a .meta file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I trained a custom object detector model through TensorFlow object detection module and I used mobilenetssd as my pretrained model. After training was done, I have three files:

```
 checkpoint
ckpt-11.data-00000-of-00001
ckpt-11.index
```

Additionally I have this file as well:

```
pipeline.config
```

I am trying to save this model as a pb file and I want to use the program provided in this [tutorial](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc). Can I run this program without the .meta file? How would I generate the .meta file? Additionally, where would I get the output_node_names as well?

Edit: I did manage to inference on this model using the chpt-11.index as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the model with the above files only.

The model will load weights based on the `index file ckpt-11.index` and `shard file ckpt-11.data-00000-of-00001`

Basically, `shard` file will contain the model weights and the `index` file indicates which weights are stored in which shard.
Usually, there will be only single shard, if you are training on a single machine.
For more details on save and load model using Tensorflow, you can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I been able to inference my model through Tensorflow with those checkpoint files. I would like to use OpenCV dnn module to inference on my model and it requires a frozen_model.pb or frozen_model.pbtext. I did use the provided script to convert my checkpoints into a save_model.pb, but I am stuck on converting it to a frozen model or find a program that can inference on it that is not Tensorflow.

Comment: @TylerOleson, Hey !! were you able to find a solution to this? I am stuck with the same problem. I have a .index and .data file which needs to be converted to a frozengraph format. But haven't found anything yet since all other tutorials require the '.meta' file.

Comment: Hi @MisaalD'souza, I never find a solution for this. I did managed to create a save_model.pb but not a freeze_graph.pb. I ended up using a different Object Detector.

Comment: ahh nvm ! I have to use a different approach as well now. Thanks for replying :)